# Can't include a 'tabu' inside \newenvironment with cells in the postamble

Tags: tables, environments

I'm trying to include a `tabu` inside a new definition of an environment but it fails if the postamble (`enddef`) of the new environment includes tabu's contents, so cells. With `tabular` or `tabular*` works. The error is:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero. \tabu@0.H5
```

The MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\newenvironment{testt}
{\begin{tabu} to \textwidth{cccc}
 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 \\
 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 \\}
{
 41 & 42 & 43 & 44
\end{tabu}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{testt}
 31 & 32 & 33 & 34 \\
\end{testt}
\end{document}
```

How to solve this?

Comment: This seems to be a `tabu` bug.

Comment: While not having a new version of tabu, what may be a workaround?

Answer (score 4):

Try the package `environ`. This package uses `\BODY` to markup the postion of the parameter, which avoid problems, such as mismatch of braces and what occured in this question.

See its [document](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/environ/environ.pdf).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{testt}
{\begin{tabu} to \textwidth{cccc}
 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 \\
 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 \\
 \BODY
 41 & 42 & 43 & 44
\end{tabu}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{testt}
 31 & 32 & 33 & 34 \\
\end{testt}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `tabu` package internally does

```
\tabu@collectbody#1#2\end
```

to collect up all of the content of the table before typesetting. That won't work correctly if you 'hide' any of the table. It does work if you only hide the `\end{tabu}` as for example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\newenvironment{testt}
{\begin{tabu} to \textwidth{cccc}
 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 \\
 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 \\}
{
\end{tabu}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{testt}
 31 & 32 & 33 & 34 \\
 41 & 42 & 43 & 44
\end{testt}
\end{document}
```

still grabs all of the table correctly.

You can see something is wrong if you use `\showthe\currentgrouplevel` inside the cells: all of the 'working' cases have group level 14, while the 'wrong' one is group level 8.

As egreg says, this is arguably a bug in `tabu`, or at least a 'feature' which should be documented. To advice on a work-around, I guess we need to know what effect you are after and can then suggest an alternative approach: I think that would be best as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You may try with the `collect` package. Nota bene: not having ever used neither `collect` nor `tabu` I am surely unable to expertly assess whether this is a viable and robust way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{collect}

\definecollection{rescuetabu}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{testt}
{\@nameuse{collect*}{rescuetabu}
 {\begin{tabu} to \textwidth{cccc}
 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 \\
 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 \\ }
 {41 & 42 & 43 & 44 \\ \end{tabu}}{}{}}
{\@nameuse{endcollect*}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\texttt{normal tabu}

\begin{tabu} to \textwidth{cccc}
 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 \\
 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 \\ 
 31 & 32 & 33 & 34 \\
\end{tabu}

\hrule\medskip
\texttt{rescued tabus}

\begin{testt}
 31 & 32 & 33 & 34 \\
\end{testt}

\bigskip

\begin{testt}
 51 & 52 & 53 & 54 \\
 61 & 62 & 63 & 64 \\
\end{testt}
\hrule

\end{document}
```

> [image: rescued tabu]