# longtabu newenvironment caption error

Tags: tables, captions, environments, longtable, tabu

I want to make an environment for my tables. See the following example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}           % \toprule, \bottomrule
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

  \newenvironment{kpTable}
  {
    \begin{longtabu}{X[1,c] X[1,c]}
        \toprule \rowfont{\bfseries}
        Foo & Bar\\
        \midrule
        \everyrow{\tabucline[on 3 pt off 3pt]-}
  }
  {
        \everyrow{}\\
        \bottomrule
        \caption{}  % ERROR: Missing number, treated as zero.
    \end{longtabu}
  }

  \begin{kpTable}
    1 & 2 \\
    1 & 2 \\
    1 & 2
  \end{kpTable}

\end{document}
```

[image: my table]

The `caption` statement generates the error:
"Missing number, treated as zero.  \tabu@0.H6"

How can I fix?

Comment: Try `\bottomrule%`.

Comment: @Sigur, same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it using the `environ` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}           % \toprule, \bottomrule
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{environ}

\begin{document}

  \NewEnviron{kpTable}
  {
    \begin{longtabu}{X[1,c] X[1,c]}
        \toprule \rowfont{\bfseries}
        Foo & Bar\\
        \midrule
        \everyrow{\tabucline[on 3 pt off 3pt]-}
        \BODY
        \everyrow{}\\
        \bottomrule
        \caption{}
    \end{longtabu}
  }

  \begin{kpTable}
    1 & 2 \\
    1 & 2 \\
    1 & 2
  \end{kpTable}

\end{document}
```

As mentioned in Ch'en Meng's answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106717/cant-include-a-tabu-inside-newenvironment-with-cells-in-the-postamble)