# Macro to create entries in tabularray in user defined environment

Tags: tables, macros, environments, expansion, tabularray

I need a macro to create entries (rows) in a table. As proposed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139242/46718) I was successfully using the `environ` package together with the `tabu` one. Since `tabu` is not maintained, I decided to switch to `tabularray` package.

Unfortunately `tabularray` is not easy to use with macros inside. I tried to pass the `\BODY` command to the `expand` option without success:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{tabletest}{
  \begin{tblr}[expand=\BODY]
    {colspec = {X[6,l,m]X[1,c,m]X[0.5,c,m]X[1,r,m]},
    rowsep = {3mm},
    rowhead = 1, rowfoot = 1,
    row{odd} = {gray!20}, row{even} = {gray!5},
    row{Z} = {gray} % last line
    }
    \SetRow{12mm, c, bg=gray, font=\large\bfseries} Title & A & B & C \\
    
    \BODY

    This & is & last & row \\
  \end{tblr}
}

\newcommand{\addrow}[4]{#1 & #2 & #3 & #4 \\}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabletest}
  This & is & a & line \\
  This & is & a & line \\
%  \addrow{This}{is}{a}{test}       <-- not working !
\end{tabletest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to create all lines with the `\addrow` macro. How can I achieve this? Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm just curious. What is the advantage of using a custom command to generate table entries instead of the usual `stuff1 & stuff2 & etc.\\\` ?

Comment: I'm working on a class which allows to create invoices easily. Have a look at https://framagit.org/Globulle/invoice-template-latex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this could work:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{tabletest}{+b}
 {
  \begin{tblr}[expand=\addrow]
    {colspec = {X[6,l,m]X[1,c,m]X[0.5,c,m]X[1,r,m]},
    rowsep = {3mm},
    rowhead = 1, rowfoot = 1,
    row{odd} = {gray!20}, row{even} = {gray!5},
    row{Z} = {gray} % last line
    }
    \SetRow{12mm, c, bg=gray, font=\large\bfseries} Title & A & B & C \\
    
    #1

    This & is & last & row \\
  \end{tblr}
}{}

\newcommand{\addrow}[4]{#1 & #2 & #3 & #4 \\}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabletest}
  This & is & a & line \\
  This & is & a & line \\
  \addrow{This}{is}{a}{test}       
\end{tabletest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I'm not familiar with `\NewDocumentEnvironment`. Could you precise what `+b` means?

Comment: basically it does the same as the environ package, see the documentation of xparse.

Comment: OK. Is `xparse` internally called by `tabularray`?

Comment: It is part of a current LaTeX format.

Comment: @Tobard You should read the last version of `usrguide`. Type `texdoc usrguide` on a Unix system.